# GraalVM native image build `nativeCompile` task fails on Gradle after migrating from Java11 to Java17

Tags: java, migration, build.gradle, micronaut, graalvm

In summary, after migrating Gradle properties (source/target) and native GraalVM image from Java11 to Java17, the build task fails on Gradle.

This is a micronaut Java service and without giving away any proprietary codebase details, I'm sharing the following portion of my Gradle's output of the failed 'nativeCompile' task:

```
[1/7] Initializing...                                                                                    (8.0s @ 0.36GB)
 Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.1 Java 17 CE'
 Java version info: '17.0.6+10-jvmci-22.3-b13'
 C compiler: gcc (redhat, aarch64, 8.5.0)
 Garbage collector: Serial GC
 6 user-specific feature(s)
 - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
 - io.micronaut.buffer.netty.NettyFeature
 - io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.graal.ChecksumFeature
 - io.micronaut.grpc.server.graalvm.HttpNettyFeature
 - io.micronaut.http.netty.graal.HttpNettyFeature
 - io.micronaut.jackson.JacksonDatabindFeature

Fatal error: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        0.5s (5.9% of total time) in 12 GCs | Peak RSS: 1.26GB | CPU load: 2.25
========================================================================================================================
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class io.micronaut.grpc.server.graalvm.HttpNettyFeature (in unnamed module @0x128ca7af) cannot access class com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.SystemPropertiesSupport (in module org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder) because module org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder does not export com.oracle.svm.core.jdk to unnamed module @0x128ca7af
        at io.micronaut.grpc.server.graalvm.HttpNettyFeature.beforeAnalysis(HttpNettyFeature.java:84)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$9(NativeImageGenerator.java:736)
Failed generating 'application' after 8.2s.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:85)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:736)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:578)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:535)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:403)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:580)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1

> Task :nativeCompile FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':nativeCompile'.
> Process 'command '/opt/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.1/bin/native-image'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have no experience with GraalVM (this is legacy, and am running the `nativeCompile` inside a container that was created like this:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash \
 --mount type=bind,source=<path to service source code>,target=/app \
 --mount type=bind,source=<path to home>.gradle,target=/root/.gradle \
 ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:ol8-java17-22.3.1
```

On this container, the env details are as follows:

```
bash-4.4# ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-11-25 13:35:10 UTC
Revision:     daece9dbc5b79370cc8e4fd6fe4b2cd400e150a8

Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.6 (GraalVM Community 17.0.6+10-jvmci-22.3-b13)
OS:           Linux 5.15.49-linuxkit aarch64
```

I have little idea of what to pursue here, would like to know if there is a native dependency that is outdated. I know I haven't posted my `build.gradle` nut hopefully someone can give me some pointers so far.

Comment: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/8160 may help

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. Seems like GraalVM publishes updates that must be used in lockstep with older minor versions. I guess it's a way to keep native classes compatible.

In my case, the older native image, gradle and code base setup was using ol8-java11-22.1.0 and I updated it all to ol8-java17-23.2.1, the latest available. This broke the build.

However, GraalVM also publishes ol8-java17-22.1.0 which matches the older minor versions. This worked without any issues, built successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I build the native image using the `native-image` command directly instead of through the gradle plugin. I ran into this issue when upgrading graalvm from `22.1.0` to `22.3.2`. Adding the argument, `-J--add-exports=org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.jdk=ALL-UNNAMED`, to the native-image command fixed it.